# Can I send a message from the web app to a portable area on MvcContrib.Bus

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, mvccontrib, portable-areas

Before I get too stuck in, I wondered if anyone had done this.

All the examples I look at of MvcContrib.Bus show the message being sent by the portable area, to the host.  I would like to be able to then send a message back from the host to the portable area and wondered if this was possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can :)

The bus messages can be received by the area as well as sent.